# Binary Classification model open cv error

Tags: python, opencv, classification

I am working on a binary classification model having a problem with looping over my dataset folder

thats my code

```
X = []
y = []
counter = 0
for image in train_data:    
    #print(image)
    img = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    #print(img)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (nrows, ncolumns), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    X.append(img)

    if counter <= 3500:
      y.append(1)
    elif counter > 3500:
      y.append(0)
    counter +=1
return X, y
```

the error is

error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:4044: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

Please advise
Thanks

Comment: What is the value for the tuple (nrows, ncolumns)?

Comment: @TiagoDuque
nrows = 150
ncolumns = 150
channel = 3

Comment: This error happens also if image is None

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi how to avoid it? i am naming the images from 1:7000 so the possibility that one of them is missing might be there.. also i am looping over the folder.. is there a way around that?

Comment: Check it at runtime. <<If image is None:>>...

Comment: @TiagoDuque i have done it, try and except since there was missing images

Comment: Is the problem happening now? Just make sure not to lose the counter increment.